# php : move an element having a certain attribute value at the end of the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have sorted  an array of travel products by price .
i'd like to move the products with a price =0 at the end of the list.

Here is what i have tried:

```
        for($i = 0; $i < count($mes_voyages); ++$i) {

            if($mes_voyages[i]['prix']==0) 
            {

                array_push($mes_voyages,$mes_voyages[i]);
                unset($mes_voyages[i]);

            }

        }
```

Comment: This is probably pseudo-code, but in case you didn't know: PHP variables start with `$`.

Comment: oops i got tired ;) thanx...it works now with $i

Comment: It happens. Glad to know you got it working :)

Comment: You will skip every item that comes after an item with price 0 this way ;-)

Comment: so what is the problem of your code?

Comment: i have forgotten the $ before the i

Comment: @Matoeil - please accept one answer if your question had been solved

Answer (score 3):

So that will be:

```
$mes_voyages = array_merge(
   array_filter($mes_voyages, function($item){ return $item['prix']!=0; }),
   array_filter($mes_voyages, function($item){ return $item['prix']==0; })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a much cleaner solution:

```
usort($mes_voyages, function($a,$b) {
     if ($a["prix"] === 0 && $a["prix"] != $b["prix"]) return 1;
});
```

Comment: Hm. Not sure that will do the stuff. Sorting callback function should return full set `-1 or 0 or 1` for proper result. That need to be tested properly

Comment: it does not work combined with my previous treatment to the array which is  function cmp($a, $b)
   {if ($a["prix"] == $b["prix"]) {
     return 0;
    }
    return ($a["prix"]  < $b["prix"] ) ? -1 : 1;
   }   
   usort($mes_voyages, "cmp");